# JBox2D simple example for Android?

Tags: android, box2d

I'm starting to develop an Android game. I've already installed jBox2D but I can't find complete code to develop a simple application from scratch using this framework.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried out [the testbed](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/downloads/list)? This lets will let you play with the physics and get a feel for how it works, and the source is included for each test, so you can get an idea of what does what. [The wiki](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/wiki/Testbed) explains how to add tests. This is the best resource I know of for getting acquainted with the engine, you may look for Box2d examples in C++ and try and adapt them, as it's much more prolific.